# Nearest Neighbor distance frequency distribution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, nearest-neighbor, distribution

I have a dataset of 6455 points. Is there a way to produce the frequency distribution of nearest neighbour distances in the data set in ArcGIS 10.3?
The Average Nearest Neighbor tool only produces the mean distance, not the whole distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Generate Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000) to obtain the nearest neighbour distances and then use a pivot table in excel to create the [frequecy distribution](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/frequency-distribution.html). That should work.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. If the 'Generate Near Table tool' would have been visible in the toolbox when using the basic level license (as I usually do), perhaps I could have figured it out myself...

Comment: Glad it did! Could you please mark my answer as the best answer. That is the best way express thanks here! Have a good day.